# Dont work text insertion In Imacros (slack.com)

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to put "hello" in message field e.g. https://r-data-team.slack.com/messages/D9V9D91JN/

I write in js file this, but nothing happens

```
iimPlayCode('TAG SELECTOR="#msg_input>.ql-editor>p" CONTENT=hello')
```

"#msg_input>.ql-editor>p " is defined, problem in TAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No magic so far, just the **Event mode** used:

```
iimPlayCode (
    'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#msg_input>DIV" BUTTON=0' + "\n" +
    'EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#msg_input>DIV" CHARS="hello"' + "\n"
);
```

Comment: wow, thank you. But I have one more problem: I need send message, pressing ENTER.I wrote: EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#msg_input>DIV" KEY=13   , but it just move to a new line.